# Implementing dynamic methods in rails for key/value pair

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic-method

Let's say I have a database table called 'options' with corresponding model called Option. Structure of this table is simple and as follows ...

```
id    -> primary key, auto increment
name  -> key
value -> value for the key
```

Sample data rows could be as follows ...

```
id   name                         value     
---- ---------------------------- -----------
1    default_view                 DAILY     
2    show_registration_number     0         
3    notification_method          IMMEDIATE
```

What I want is that all the options (keys) should be accessible to me as the method names.

For example if do as following ...

```
@options = Options.find(:all)
```

is it possible to access the data like `@options.default_view` which should return me the value as 'DAILY' and similarly `@options.show_registration_number` which should return the value as 0.

Also if that is possible, whether modification would be permissible like if `@options.default_view = 'MONTHLY'` and should update the corresponding record in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you *almost* the answer you were looking for:  http://code.dblock.org/how-to-define-enums-in-ruby

It relies on `const_missing` and assumes that elements of your "enum" are defined as constants, in your case `Option::default_view`

However, it is easy to see how to adapt this code to use `method_missing` so that you can do `Option.default_view`

Another example of this same approach is contained in [rails-settings](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings) gem, so you can browse [this code](https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings/blob/master/lib/rails-settings/settings.rb) for the answer you are looking for